# Gradient usage on GraphicsPath object

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently trying to apply a gradient to a GraphicsPath object. My code is as follows:

```
import flash.display.*;

var style:GraphicsStroke = new GraphicsStroke(3);
style.fill = new GraphicsGradientFill('linear',[0xFF0000,0x00FF00],[1,1],[0,255]);
var line_commands:Vector.<int> = new <int>[1,2];
var line_points:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[0,0,800,600];
var line:GraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath(line_commands, line_points);

var image:Vector.<IGraphicsData> = new <IGraphicsData>[style, line];
graphics.drawGraphicsData(image);
```

If I'm not mistaken, the stroke used should cause the line to linearly fade between red and green with full red being at 0,0 and full green at 800,600. When run, however, there is no full red and only a tiny hint of the fade around the 0,0 point. I've been messing around with options for a couple hours to no avail... anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `matrix` parameter for gradient fill object.

```
var mat:matrix=new Matrix();
mat.createGradientBox(800,600);
style.fill.matrix=mat;
```

Comment: Is the matrix parameter necessary? I figured leaving it null would just fade over the GraphicsPath according to the start/end points of the path and ratio parameter.

Comment: Yes, the gradient fill cannot determine the width/height of the gradient prior to you drawing the complete path, and these objects are not exchanging information with each other. So you predefine the gradient area by providing the proper matrix.

Comment: I see! Thank you for that clarification, Vesper; I'm a little disappointed, but at least I'm informed... answer accepted.